# how to redirect the user from a servlet to a new html file inside my web project based on an input parameter?

Tags: html, servlets, redirect

I want to develop an employee management system where the user choose a table inside the database ,myServlet get the chosen button then user will be redirected to another html page to choose action on that table.
i failed to redirect the user using response.sendRedirect("empActions.html")
 so any help??

here is myFirst html page to choose a table from database:

```
<form action="chooseTable" method="post">
<h1>choose a table: </h1>
<input type="button" value="Employees" name="emp">
<input type="button" value="Managers" name="mng">
<input type="button" value="Departments" name="deprt">
</form>
```

And here's the FirstMainServelet.java to redirect to an html page :
package com.example;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class FirstMainServelet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          String e = request.getParameter("button");
           if(e.equals("Employees"))
            {
                response.sendRedirect("empActions.html");
                System.out.println(" selected action is  "+e);
            }
            else if(e.equals("Managers"))
            {
                response.sendRedirect( "mngActions.html");
                System.out.println(" selected action is  "+e);

            }
            else if(e .equals("Departments"))
            {  
               System.out.println(" selected action is  "+e);
               response.sendRedirect( "dptActions.html");       }
           }
}
```

web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>FirstServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlet.FirstMainServelet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/chooseTable </url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: For one, don't use fully qualified paths in redirects

Comment: While perhaps being bad practice, the fully qualified path should still work.  What error message do you get?

Comment: `response.sendRedirect("SelectTable.html")` write instead of `response.sendRedirect("http:127.0.0.1:MYPROJECT/SelectTable.html")`

Comment: @James_Parsons Actually I am brand new to java technologies .

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there is no error i just click on the button and Nothin happen !!

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli that didn't work either .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your WAR file has the following structure:

```
- your_project.war
----- META-INF
-------- MANIFEST.MF
----- WEB-INF
-------- classes
-------- lib
-------- web.xml
----- pages 
-------- empActions.html 
-------- mngActions.html
-------- dptActions.html
```

Then you need the following code to redirect to the correct HTML page:

```
if(e.equals("Employees")) {
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/pages/empActions.html");
    System.out.println(" selected action is  " + e);
}
```